# How to check if reactive a dataframe exists in session and set value in a list as 'NA' if it does not

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, markdown, pagedown

I am working on a feature which allows my markdown file to conditionally execute chunks based on a parameters sent from my shiny app. Some information about how this works here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Within the `downloadhandler()` there is an argument which calls upon `params =`  which I give it a list, for example that list would look like this;
`params <- list(report_name = input$J, data = data(), data2 = data2())`

So my aim is to have an if else statement that would code data2 to be `NULL` or `NA` with the following; `data2 = if( exists("data2") ) {data2()} else {NA}`

This would allow me to stop some chunks in markdown from running by setting the `eval='someconditionthatsfalse'` if `data2()` does not exists or is empty in some way.

The issue I am running into is that this always exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**A reprex to help with the problem.**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("simulate", "go"),
  textOutput("doesitexist")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$doesitexist <- renderText({
    
    if( exists("data2") ) {print("yes it exists")} else {print("not it does not exist")}
    
  })

  
  data2 <- eventReactive(input$simulate, {
    data.frame(x = 1)
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  First, `data2` is an observer of your button rather than the `data.frame` whose existence you want to test.  It will always exist within your server function, that's why it your test for existence always returns `TRUE`.  Second, because - however you’ve set things up - your reactive will always exist within the server function, `exists` won't work.  You need to use another condition and take an indirect approach.  I've chosen to use `reactiveValues`.

[You could also use `reactiveValue`, but I prefer `reactiveValues` even when I have only one reactive value to deal with because the syntax remains the same when moving from one reactive value to more than one.]

I set the reactive value to `NA` to start with, and test for existence with `is.na`.

Here's some working code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("simulate", "Go"),
  textOutput("doesitexist")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(data2=NA)

  output$doesitexist <- renderText({
    if (is.na(v$data2)) "No, it doesn't exist" else "Yes, it does exist"
  })

  observeEvent(input$simulate, { v$data2 <- data.frame(x=1)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code and for the detailed explanation. I managed to implement this style of using `reactiveValues` into my script and everything is working great!